# Calculate days between to dates postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, date-format, date-math

I'm having a problem:

I'm trying to calculate days between two dates.

Let's say I have the date **'2005-05-25 06:04:08'** and I want to count how many days are from that day to the current date.

I tried doing:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', AGE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2005-05-25 06:04:08'::timestamp )) AS days;
```

But for some reason this returns 11, it's not taking into count the HUGE difference in years. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `AGE()` function may be causing the issue, as the correct use of `DATE_PART()` would look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '2005-05-25 06:04:08'::timestamp) AS days;
```

Note that this would return the number of full days between the current time stamp and the provided start. So the difference between `2021-01-01 02:30:00` and `2021-01-02 00:00:00` would be `0`, as no full day had passed. If you need to count days from midnight, then ypercube™’s solution is the way to go

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - '2005-05-25 06:04:08'::date AS days ;
```